# Can't use variable outside function even after setting it global

Tags: php, variables, gd, php-gd

I have made a script to generate thumbnails using PHP's GD library. The thing is that the original images are in their respective directories that are assigned to `'gallery/'.$section;`and the thumbs will go in the directory `'gallery/thumbs/'.$section`

Now, every time the script is executed i want it to check if the thumbnail already exist and if not only then create it but whenever i call the function and reload the page it creates new thumbnail every time.

**I know it is about the scope of the variable inside and outside the function but what it is I can't figure out. I've tried setting the variable as global but still it is not working out.**

Here is the pre-declaration. The `idir` is for images directory and the `tdir`is for thumbs directory.

```
<?php
$idir = "gallery/".$section.'/';
$tdir="gallery/thumbs/".$section.'/';
if(!file_exists($tdir)){
mkdir($tdir);
}
```

Here is the function i am using.

```
function createThumbs($idir, $tdir, $tw, $th){
    $dir=opendir($idir);
    while(($fname = readdir($dir)) != false){
        if($fname!='.' && $fname != '..'){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($idir.$fname);

        $width = imagesx($img);
        $height = imagesy($img);

        if($width>$height){
            $new_width=$tw;
            $new_height=$height*($tw/$width);
        }
        if ($width < $height) 
        {
            $new_width=$width*($th/$height);
            $new_height=$th;
        }
        if ($width == $height) 
        {
            $new_width=$tw;
            $new_height=$th;
        }


        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0,0,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($tmp_img, $tdir.$fname, 100);

        imagedestroy($tmp_img); 
        imagedestroy($img); 
    }
}
closedir($dir); 
}
```

And after this i am calling the function like that.

```
if (!file_exists($tdir.$fname)) {
    createThumbs($idir,$tdir,250, 200);
}
```

Also when calling the function it gives an error - `undefined variable .$fname`.

Comment: that means `$fname` has not been defined ... and based on the code displayed it has not been.

Comment: $fname = readdir($dir)

Comment: Ok, you have `$fname` in a function, but what is `$fname` in `file_exists` clause?

Comment: yes, that is the problem. I want to check if the $fname exist and i want to check that outside of the function.

Comment: So what is the value of `$fname` outside th function? Do you set it or what?

Comment: dude! the value of $fname inside the function is each file's name. Now i want to check if the file with $fname already exist - outside the function. So i want to know what to do with $fname outside the function. how to set it. If set it or not

Comment: dude! Do you understand how your code works? First it gets value of `$fname`. It doens't know anything about your function or what will be going on next. It just takes value of `$fname` and checks it. If you didn't set value of `$fname` earlier there's nothing to check.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for the info. But could you also tell me the way to set it to the current file name. Thanks man.

Comment: What is it - current file name?

Comment: @u_mulder thanks man. But I think somebody posted the right answer. Anyway thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You intialize the value for `$fname` inside the function, then the first time you try to get `$fname` value it is never been initialized, thus the error you get.

It could help you move the if statement inside the while loop:

```
function createThumbs($idir, $tdir, $tw, $th){

    $dir=opendir($idir);
    while(($fname = readdir($dir)) != false){
        if($fname!='.' && $fname != '..' && !file_exists($tdir.$fname)){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($idir.$fname);

        $width = imagesx($img);
        $height = imagesy($img);

        if($width>$height){
            $new_width=$tw;
            $new_height=$height*($tw/$width);
        }
        if ($width < $height) 
        {
            $new_width=$width*($th/$height);
            $new_height=$th;
        }
        if ($width == $height) 
        {
            $new_width=$tw;
            $new_height=$th;
        }


        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0,0,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($tmp_img, $tdir.$fname, 100);

        imagedestroy($tmp_img); 
        imagedestroy($img); 
        }
    }
    closedir($dir); 
}
```

And then always call thumbnail creation:

```
//if (!file_exists($tdir.$fname)) {
    createThumbs($idir,$tdir,250, 200);
//}
```

Comment: Yep. That helps. Thanks man. But are you sure that this is the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Not sure about efficiency of this solution, it just fix the code you proposed. I suggest you to use a profiler for that.